# How to make cardview background as a shape of a rectangle with elongated botton right corner

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a cardview to look like as in the image below. How to a create shape with rectangle with elongated botton right corner in the drawable and apply it as a background to a cardview? OR is there a better way to achieve this result?

[image]

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Android java. So in xml?

Comment: https://arkapp.medium.com/trapezium-view-for-android-584799c7e849
Refer to this article